# Como incluir prelude.jspf em java config spring boot

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Estou migrando uma aplicação Spring MVC 3 para Spring boot, essa aplicação tinha seu web.xml com a configuração de prelude.jspf onde continham todos os imports JSTL das jsps. Quero migrar essa configuração do xml para java config mas não encontrei nenhuma referência. Segue configuração do web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/pages/prelude.jspf</include-prelude>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia?